# Laravel Eloquent multiple database

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have multiple database connected into my web app.

These are: `write` and `read`

I have this eloquent database query:

`$users = User::whereIsAdmin(0)->get();`

I want this db query to use the `read` database since by default my app is reading in the `write` database.

How would I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the source code of Laravel Eloquent Models, and here:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L303

It says `on` should be used to change connections.

So:

```
User::on("read")->whereIsAdmin(0)->get();
```

Comment: I will try that. That looks promising :)

Comment: I am getting this error: `Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setConnection() should not be called statically`

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: perfect! This is what i'm looking for :)